# what is causing this app freeze?

Tags: windows, windbg, freeze

My .NET application goes in hang state. I don't see anything on the manages side that can give any clues. I ran !threads command (locks count colulmn is 0 for all threads), nothing out of !syncblk etc. This application does interop and on the native side I see following stacks. Any ideas what is causing application freeze or how to debug this issue?

```
    0:040> ~*kv  
   0  Id: 358.35c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdf000 Unfrozen   
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child                
0012e124 7c90df4a 7c809590 00000002 0012e150 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])  
0012e128 7c809590 00000002 0012e150 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])  
0012e1c4 7e4195f9 00000002 0012e1ec 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  
0012e220 7752ebd6 00000001 0012e520 0000038a user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e (FPO: [5,13,4])  
0012e248 77557237 0012e520 0000038a 0012e274 ole32!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x80 (FPO: [3,0,4])  
0012e2bc 79f9e14d 00000002 000003e8 00000001 ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0xcf (FPO: [5,21,4])  
0012e2dc 79f9e0b4 00000000 000003e8 00000001 mscorwks!NT5WaitRoutine+0x51 (FPO: [5,1,0])  
0012e348 79f9e018 00000001 0012e520 00000000 mscorwks!MsgWaitHelper+0xa5 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  
0012e368 79f4c664 00000001 0012e520 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x28 (FPO: [5,0,4])  
0012e3ec 79f4c6f9 00000001 0012e520 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x13c (FPO: [5,22,4])  
0012e43c 79f15a68 00000001 0012e520 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  
* WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll  
0012e540 792b68af 00000000 00000000 2d7e9448 mscorwks!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x156 (FPO: [2,53,4])  
0012e55c 792b6865 000003e8 00000000 7931782c mscorlib_ni+0x1f68af  
* WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll  
0012e574 7b6f1a4f 00000000 00000103 0000c169 mscorlib_ni+0x1f6865  
0012e58c 7ba2d68b f2808aa3 79e7a6e8 0012e724 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x721a4f  
0012e620 7b6f33ac 00000001 2d53e4d0 2d53e4b0 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0xa5d68b  
0012e65c 7b920bd7 2d53e4d0 2d7e9434 2d7e9414 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x7233ac  
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll  
0012e674 7a924362 1cf2ac80 01f61e7c 00000001 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x950bd7  
0012e6a8 7a922a93 1cf2ac80 7e42b372 00000000 System_ni+0x4e4362  
0012e6f4 7a923f8f 1cf2ac80 00000003 00000000 System_ni+0x4e2a93  

   1  Id: 358.534 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffde000 Unfrozen  
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child                
00a5fe38 7c90df4a 7c809590 00000003 00a5fe64 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])  
00a5fe3c 7c809590 00000003 00a5fe64 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])  
00a5fed8 7c80a115 00000003 00a5ff1c 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  
00a5fef4 79f025c1 00000003 00a5ff1c 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18 (FPO: [4,0,0])  
00a5ff54 79f0251e f225e651 00000000 79f013dc mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::MainLoop+0xe9 (FPO: [0,14,4])  
00a5ff84 79f02445 f225e661 79f90dc1 79f013dc mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProc+0xe5 (FPO: [0,6,4])  
00a5ffb4 7c80b729 00000000 79f90dc1 79f013dc mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProcStatic+0x9c (FPO: [1,6,4])  
00a5ffec 00000000 79f023ff 00000000 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  

   2  Id: 358.550 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdd000 Unfrozen  
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child                
00c2fcd0 7c90df4a 7c809590 00000002 00c2fcfc ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])  
00c2fcd4 7c809590 00000002 00c2fcfc 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])  
00c2fd70 7c80a115 00000002 7a3b8d28 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  
00c2fd8c 79f92c5b 00000002 7a3b8d28 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18 (FPO: [4,0,0])  
00c2fdac 79f970b8 0016d480 00c2feb0 0016dc80 mscorwks!WKS::WaitForFinalizerEvent+0x77 (FPO: [1,0,0])  
00c2fdc0 79e984cf 00c2feb0 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x49 (FPO: [1,0,0])  
00c2fdd4 79e9846b 00c2feb0 00c2fe5c 79f7762b mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x32a (FPO: [1,0,0])  
00c2fe68 79e98391 00c2feb0 f242e771 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0xe3 (FPO: [1,28,4])  
00c2fea4 79eef74c 00c2feb0 00000000 00157640 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x30a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  
00c2fecc 79eef75d 79f9706d 00000008 00c2ff14 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition+0x32 (FPO: [2,7,0])  
00c2fedc 79f3c6bc 79f9706d f242e6c1 00000000 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase+0xd (FPO: [1,0,0])  
00c2ff14 79f920a5 00000000 84123270 804fb078 mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0xbb (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  
00c2ffb4 7c80b729 0016dc80 00730074 00610020 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49 (FPO: [1,1,0])  
00c2ffec 00000000 79f9205f 0016dc80 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  

   3  Id: 358.9c4 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffd9000 Unfrozen  
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child                
0d0ffe50 7c90df4a 7c809590 00000002 0d0ffe7c ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])  
0d0ffe54 7c809590 00000002 0d0ffe7c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])  
0d0ffef0 7e4195f9 00000002 0d0fff18 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  
0d0fff4c 7e4196a8 00000001 0d0fffac ffffffff user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e (FPO: [5,13,4])  
0d0fff68 4ec6730c 00000001 0d0fffac 00000000 user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjects+0x1f (FPO: [5,0,0])  
0d0fffb4 7c80b729 00000000 00000000 0c12eb28 GdiPlus!BackgroundThreadProc+0x59 (FPO: [1,9,4])  
0d0fffec 00000000 4ec672b0 00000000 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])  

   4  Id: 358.9d4 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffd8000 Unfrozen  
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child                
0d6fff98 7c90d21a 7c927f22 00000001 0d6fffac ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])  
0d6fff9c 7c927f22 00000001 0d6fffac 00000000 ntdll!NtDelayExecution+0xc (FPO: [2,0,0])  
0d6fffb4 7c80b729 00000000 00000000 00000014 ntdll!RtlpTimerThread+0x47 (FPO: [1,2,0])
0d6fffec 00000000 7c927edb 00000000 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

   5  Id: 358.9f0 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffd6000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0da2fe14 7c90daaa 77e765e3 000004b4 0da2ff74 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
0da2fe18 77e765e3 000004b4 0da2ff74 00000000 ntdll!NtReplyWaitReceivePortEx+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
0da2ff80 77e76caf 0da2ffa8 77e76ad1 0020ffd0 rpcrt4!LRPC_ADDRESS::ReceiveLotsaCalls+0x12a (FPO: [0,14,0])
0da2ff88 77e76ad1 0020ffd0 7c900000 00f2fae0 rpcrt4!RecvLotsaCallsWrapper+0xd (FPO: [1,0,0])
0da2ffa8 77e76c97 00177830 0da2ffec 7c80b729 rpcrt4!BaseCachedThreadRoutine+0x79 (FPO: [1,2,4])
0da2ffb4 7c80b729 0023c988 7c900000 00f2fae0 rpcrt4!ThreadStartRoutine+0x1a (FPO: [1,0,0])
0da2ffec 00000000 77e76c7d 0023c988 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

   6  Id: 358.9f4 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffd5000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0db2fe14 7c90daaa 77e765e3 000004b4 0db2ff74 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
0db2fe18 77e765e3 000004b4 0db2ff74 00000000 ntdll!NtReplyWaitReceivePortEx+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
0db2ff80 77e76caf 0db2ffa8 77e76ad1 0020ffd0 rpcrt4!LRPC_ADDRESS::ReceiveLotsaCalls+0x12a (FPO: [0,14,0])
0db2ff88 77e76ad1 0020ffd0 0da2fa84 00110010 rpcrt4!RecvLotsaCallsWrapper+0xd (FPO: [1,0,0])
0db2ffa8 77e76c97 00177830 0db2ffec 7c80b729 rpcrt4!BaseCachedThreadRoutine+0x79 (FPO: [1,2,4])
0db2ffb4 7c80b729 0d8032b8 0da2fa84 00110010 rpcrt4!ThreadStartRoutine+0x1a (FPO: [1,0,0])
0db2ffec 00000000 77e76c7d 0d8032b8 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

   7  Id: 358.cd0 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffaf000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0ea1fed0 7c90d21a 7c8023f1 00000001 0ea1ff04 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
0ea1fed4 7c8023f1 00000001 0ea1ff04 00000000 ntdll!NtDelayExecution+0xc (FPO: [2,0,0])
0ea1ff2c 79fd8ae1 00007530 00000001 0ea1ff9c kernel32!SleepEx+0x61 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0ea1ffa8 79fd898f 00000000 0ea1ffec 7c80b729 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadFire+0x6d (FPO: [0,21,4])
0ea1ffb4 7c80b729 0012e244 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadStart+0x57 (FPO: [1,0,0])
0ea1ffec 00000000 79fd8937 0012e244 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

   8  Id: 358.d14 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffae000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0eb1ff50 7c90da4a 7c80a7e6 000006f8 0eb1ffa4 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
0eb1ff54 7c80a7e6 000006f8 0eb1ffa4 0eb1ff98 ntdll!NtRemoveIoCompletion+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
0eb1ff80 650142a0 000006f8 0eb1ffac 0eb1ffa4 kernel32!GetQueuedCompletionStatus+0x29 (FPO: [5,4,0])
0eb1ffb4 7c80b729 00000000 008d0000 7c910222 System_Data!SNIAsyncWait+0x6c (FPO: [1,4,0])
0eb1ffec 00000000 65014234 00000000 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

   9  Id: 358.a30 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffad000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0fbfff84 7c90df4a 5b891374 00000002 0fbfffac ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
0fbfff88 5b891374 00000002 0fbfffac 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
0fbfffb4 7c80b729 00000000 0012d4c8 7c90e920 netapi32!NetbiosWaiter+0x73 (FPO: [1,2,0])
0fbfffec 00000000 5b891301 00000000 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

  10  Id: 358.cf8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffaa000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
1011ff04 7c90df5a 7c8025db 000008d8 00000001 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
1011ff08 7c8025db 000008d8 00000001 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
1011ff6c 49aa0ad3 000008d8 ffffffff 00000001 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1011ff80 77c3a3b0 49b97000 000000c0 46000000 inkobj!CComDllModule::ApcThreadProc+0x53 (FPO: [1,0,0])
1011ffb4 7c80b729 008b8fa8 000000c0 46000000 msvcrt!_endthreadex+0xa9 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1011ffec 00000000 77c3a341 008b8fa8 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

  11  Id: 358.cfc Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa9000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
1021fe44 7c90df4a 7c809590 00000002 1021fe70 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
1021fe48 7c809590 00000002 1021fe70 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
1021fee4 7e4195f9 00000002 1021ff0c 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1021ff40 49aa1353 00000001 49b970a0 ffffffff user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e (FPO: [5,13,4])
1021ff80 77c3a3b0 49b97000 000000c0 46000000 inkobj!CComDllModule::HookThreadProc+0x51 (FPO: [1,7,0])
1021ffb4 7c80b729 008b9038 000000c0 46000000 msvcrt!_endthreadex+0xa9 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1021ffec 00000000 77c3a341 008b9038 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

  12  Id: 358.d04 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa8000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
1031fe0c 7c90df4a 7c809590 0000000b 22e955f8 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
1031fe10 7c809590 0000000b 22e955f8 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
1031feac 775649b8 0000000b 23f14c38 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1031ff28 49a96bf9 00000002 ffffffff 0000000b ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0x100 (FPO: [5,21,4])
1031ff78 49aa1395 1031ffb4 77c3a3b0 0ff32290 inkobj!CWaitProcThread::ThisThreadProc+0xf6 (FPO: [0,10,0])
1031ff80 77c3a3b0 0ff32290 0061006c 774ec738 inkobj!CWaitProcThread::DispatchThreadProc+0x18 (FPO: [1,0,0])
1031ffb4 7c80b729 008b9158 0061006c 774ec738 msvcrt!_endthreadex+0xa9 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1031ffec 00000000 77c3a341 008b9158 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

  13  Id: 358.d44 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa7000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
1051fc20 7c90df5a 7c8025db 000006c8 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
1051fc24 7c8025db 000006c8 00000000 1051fc58 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
1051fc88 79e8c639 000006c8 00013c68 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1051fccc 79e8c56f 000006c8 00013c68 00000000 mscorwks!PEImage::LoadImage+0x1af (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1051fd1c 79e8c58e 00013c68 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x117 (FPO: [3,11,4])
1051fd30 79fd88a3 00013c68 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!CLREvent::Wait+0x17 (FPO: [3,0,0])
1051fdb0 79fd8d31 0d822798 00013c68 00000000 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::SafeWait+0x73 (FPO: [3,21,4])
1051fe14 79f920a5 00000000 a84b4b18 ff4b9bd0 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x11c (FPO: [1,16,4])
1051ffb4 7c80b729 0d870900 0012f374 0012eef0 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49 (FPO: [1,1,0])
1051ffec 00000000 79f9205f 0d870900 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

  14  Id: 358.d40 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa6000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
1061f42c 7c90df4a 7c809590 00000001 1061f458 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
1061f430 7c809590 00000001 1061f458 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
1061f4cc 79f4c92a 00000001 1061f70c 00000001 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1061f534 79f4c55b 00000001 1061f70c 00000001 mscorwks!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+0x6f (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1061f554 79f4c664 00000001 1061f70c 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x3c (FPO: [5,0,4])
1061f5d8 79f4c6f9 00000001 1061f70c 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x13c (FPO: [5,22,4])
1061f628 79f15a68 00000001 1061f70c 00000001 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1061f72c 792b68af 00000000 00000000 01299124 mscorwks!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x156 (FPO: [2,53,4])
1061f748 792b6865 000003e8 00000000 7931bd9c mscorlib_ni+0x1f68af
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Notes.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Notes.ni.dll
1061f760 112f61e7 00000000 00000000 00000000 mscorlib_ni+0x1f6865
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
1061f7b8 792d6d66 0185791c 1061f7d8 792e01ef Notes_ni+0x1a61e7
1061f7c4 792e01ef 1061f81c 0185791c 018578c8 mscorlib_ni+0x216d66
1061f7d8 792d6ce4 0163e868 00000000 0d86e9d0 mscorlib_ni+0x2201ef
1061f7f0 79e71b4c 00000000 00000000 1061f880 mscorlib_ni+0x216ce4
1061f800 79e821f9 1061f8d0 00000000 1061f8a0 mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x33
1061f880 79e96571 1061f8d0 00000000 1061f8a0 mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa3 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1061f9b8 79e965a4 7924290c 1061fb14 1061fa4c mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x19c (FPO: [5,12,4])
1061f9d4 79e965c2 7924290c 1061fb14 1061fa4c mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x1f (FPO: [4,0,0])
1061f9ec 79f3d883 1061fa4c e2e1e201 0d86e9d0 mscorwks!MethodDescCallSite::CallWithValueTypes+0x1a (FPO: [1,0,0])
1061fbd4 79e984cf 1061fd50 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!ThreadNative::KickOffThread_Worker+0x192 (FPO: [1,115,4])

  15  Id: 358.cc8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffac000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
10c9fe08 7c90d21a 7c8023f1 00000000 10c9fe3c ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
10c9fe0c 7c8023f1 00000000 10c9fe3c 00000000 ntdll!NtDelayExecution+0xc (FPO: [2,0,0])
10c9fe64 79e8d090 000001f4 00000000 e249e74d kernel32!SleepEx+0x61 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
10c9fe98 79e8d0aa 000001f4 00000000 e249e701 mscorwks!EESleepEx+0xbb (FPO: [2,5,4])
10c9fed4 79e7c815 000001f4 00000000 10c9ffb4 mscorwks!__DangerousSwitchToThread+0x51 (FPO: [2,7,4])
10c9fee4 79fcbb4b 000001f4 85190254 00000006 mscorwks!__SwitchToThread+0xd (FPO: [1,0,0])
10c9ffb4 7c80b729 00000000 77121631 0ea1fae4 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::GateThreadStart+0xa1 (FPO: [1,19,4])
10c9ffec 00000000 79fcbab6 00000000 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])

  16  Id: 358.cdc Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa5000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
1a0bfb20 7c90df5a 7c8025db 000006c8 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
1a0bfb24 7c8025db 000006c8 00000000 1a0bfb58 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
1a0bfb88 79e8c639 000006c8 00013c68 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1a0bfbcc 79e8c56f 000006c8 00013c68 00000000 mscorwks!PEImage::LoadImage+0x1af (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
1a0bfc1c 79e8c58e 00013c68 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x117 (FPO: [3,11,4])
1a0bfc30 79fd88a3 00013c68 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!CLREvent::Wait+0x17 (FPO: [3,0,0])
1a0bfcb0 79fd8d31 0d822798 00013c68 00000000 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::SafeWait+0x73 (FPO: [3,21,4])
1a0bfd14 79f920a5 00000000 7c90d06a 7c90e45f mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x11c (FPO: [1,16,4])
1a0bffb4 7c80b729 0d803c78 00000cc8 00000003 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49 (FPO: [1,1,0])
1a0bffec 00000000 79f9205f 0d803c78 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
```

Comment: A gigantic stack trace does not a good question make.

Comment: I can totally understand but i just don't know what is a good information to post in this case. Please let me know and i will post it.

Comment: You have not told us anything about the app.  WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, dll service, etc?  Does it hang at the same point every time?  Does it hang on every machine you test on?  What kind of interop are you doing?  You really need to narrow it down before asking.  Short of remoting in to your machine and look for ourselves, there's probably not anything magical we can tell you.

Comment: Stack traces are only useful with code to go along with it. Otherwise it's just as useless to the community as it is to you. If you can narrow it down to something specific (can you turn the native modules off?) then come back with something more concrete (code is immensely helpful), then you're likely to get a better answer.

Comment: OK, its a WinForm applications that start hanging quite frequenly but only at client side. We are not able to reproduce this problem. So I start looking into dump file appraoch. The fact that in some threads I see calls to kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx, I am wondering if these are threads in wait state and are causing hangs. Reading MSDN for this API does not help much.

Comment: "i just don't know what is a good information to post in this case." That's something you're going to have to learn first. You can't expect people to dig through all this as a personal favor to you. [Here is how you learn which stacks are interesting and which are not](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/07/10/661389.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Threads 0 and 14 are each blocked in a COM call. (A managed stack trace will tell you what calls they are.)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what the forum members are telling you is that debugging multithreaded applications is hard, especially when they communicate across process boundaries like yours.

Here are a couple of pointers for debugging apps of this sort:

1. Start with a good design. It sounds irrelevant, but the biggest problem for most multithreaded apps is that they were never designed in the first place. Do you understand the interaction of the thread? What resources do they share? Do you understand how the sharing happens and how they are locked? Is the communication protocol well-understood? If you just throw threads at a problem to handle more incoming data, your app will eventually crash.
2. Log. Add optional statements that tell you where each thread is and what data they are working on. When a thread suspends, say why first.

Like I said, this is never easy, but it is a lot easier if you take the time up front really understand this sort of system.

Answer (score 1):

As also indicated by others, it looks like the app is blocked by an outstanding COM call.
It might help to know which COM servers are involved, and take a dump analyze of them as well.
I have successfully  used DebugDiag1.1 and Crash/Hang analyze to reveal which COM servers the app is waiting for.